How to add web form user controls to the Visual Studio toolbox?
This is a visual studio question.
I have a web form solution in Visual studio. I've created a number of Usercontrols within a project but I now need to use the same controls in two separate projects (within the same solution). As far as I can tell, to be able to add a reference to a control in a separate project, I need to add the usercontrol to the VS toolbox... but how?
The controls work I just need to share them across projects.
To this end I made a copy of one of the controls in the new shared-controls-library project and I renamed it to make sure it didn't conflict with my working control.
The project compiles without errors, however if I try to drag the control from the solution explorer to the toolbox, VS displays a crossed out circle.
There was mention of an option in the winforms designer to automatically add usercontrols to the toolbox, but that only seems to apply to winforms and as far as I can tell the option no longer exists for newer versions of VS.
I've also trawled through many tutiorials on writing web form user controls, but none of them mention how to publish/share them across projects.
Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong or not doing?
Edit: After posting this question a couple of discussions on stackoverflow showed up which address the subject. One mentions this article by Scott Guthrie: http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/usercontrols/usercontrols.aspx where the solution is to basically xcopy the files between projects.
A response to a similar question (Web User Controls in different Project)  indicates that the solution is to manually copy the files to a sub folder.
This just seems wrong and klunky. There has to be a better way, no?
